# Performance of OpenEdge concatenation

Tags: performance, string-concatenation, openedge, progress-4gl

I have noticed in Progress (11.4) that repeated string concatenation can be very slow. For example in the following code.

```
DEF VAR i AS INT NO-UNDO. 
DEF VAR c AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.

DO  i = 1 TO 1000000:
    c = c + STRING(i MOD 10). 
END.
```

From my experience in Java, I think the problem is that each time we are concatenating, we are copying c which is an O(n) operation, so the whole procedure is O(n^2). Java provides the `StringBuilder` class to solve this problem.

Is my analysis of the problem correct? And if so, is there a solution?

Comment: Is there an actual problem to be solved perhaps a different approach can be applied? But then we need to know about that problem.

Comment: I double the request for more details. A MEMPTR based implementation might work well as well.

Comment: 11.4? There's no 10.4 release... 10.2 is the last 10.x release.

Comment: @Jensd The problem has come up a few times. For example, we have a TEMP-TABLE of email addresses and we want to concatenate them into a string separated by semicolon.

Comment: You are right about the version, edited.

Comment: Consider storing the addresses in a second temp-table, one record per address.

Comment: I see... Then I could WRITE-JSON that temp-table and REPLACE the undesired characters, which will work assuming WRITE-JSON is O(n). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue - the following link also contains a work-around by buffering concatenations in character variables:

https://blog.abevoelker.com/introducing_bigcharacter/

Recognized by Progress and addressed in 11.7.2:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/concatenating-to-longchar-takes-exponentially-longer

Answer (score 3):

Out of curiosity, I did a test with your sample code and it completed in 266 seconds, or a little under 4.5 minutes.

Progress OpenEdge doesn't offer anything like the stringbuilder, as far as I know, but I thought our way of doing a blind append would be to a file. So I modified your code as follows:

```
etime(true).
DEF VAR I AS INT NO-UNDO. 
DEF VAR c AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
output to value(session:temp-directory + 'test.txt').
DO  i = 1 TO 1000000:
    put unformatted i mod 10.
END.
output close.
COPY-LOB FROM FILE SESSION:TEMP-DIRECTORY + 'test.txt' TO c.
disp c VIEW-AS EDITOR LARGE SIZE 70 BY 15.
MESSAGE etime
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

By taking this approach, the output time fell drastically, to a little over 0.8 seconds.

I don't know if this helps or answers your question, but as Jensd mentioned, it'd be easier if we had a practical problem to solve with this.